# CodePipeline Deploy Stage missing AWSLambda/ automatically update running ecs tasks

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, aws-code-deploy

I have a CI/CD pipeline from GitLab to AWS ECR and I would help/guidance to set up a CodePipeline that will automatically update my running image whenever a new image is pushed to ECR via GitLab CI/CD.

In CodePipeline I added GitLab in the source stage. I skipped build stage (as this done with GitLab CI/CD to ECR), and now I'm stuck at deploy stage. I cannot find AWS Lambda in the dropdown list. I copied a script (from the link below) but I cannot figure out how to add the script to the deploy stage.

The script essentially checks the image in ECR and updates the task when a push request is made to the branch in GitLab.

I used this guide as a reference https://aws.plainenglish.io/automate-application-deployment-using-aws-codepipeline-ecr-to-ecs-122feaafcd93. I understand I don't need a build stage as this is done with GitLab CI/CD but I can't figure this out

Comment: You mention ECS Tasks in your question title, but the entire question talks about Lambda and doesn't mention ECS again. It sounds like you only have a Lambda function to update, and aren't actually using ECS? Can you confirm that?

Comment: I am using ECS with Fargate. I have an docker image in ECR that my task definition points to. I'm just struggling to automatically run a new task when a new image is pushed to ECR.

Answer (score 0):

> I skipped build stage (as this done with GitLab CI/CD to ECR), and now I'm stuck at deploy stage. I cannot find AWS Lambda in the dropdown list. I copied a script (from the link below) but I cannot figure out how to add the script to the deploy stage.

So you are trying to run a script to perform some sort of custom automation in your pipeline, and you want to run that as a Lambda function. You can only do that during the build phase, as an AWS CodeBuild step. You note that you are doing the actual build elsewhere, so you skipped the build phase in your CodePipeline.

The thing to understand here is AWS CodeBuild isn't just for doing builds, it is for running any type of script/automation in a CodePipeline. You can do things like run unit tests, database migrations, etc. in CodeBuild. Don't let the name mislead you. Think of CodeBuild more as a generic script runner than an actual build engine.

So you need to add a CodeBuild step in the build phase of your pipeline. When you do that, you can select AWS Lambda as the build execution environment, and you can use your script there.

Comment: "So you are trying to run a script to perform some sort of custom automation in your pipeline, and you want to run that as a Lambda function. You can only do that during the build phase, as an AWS CodeBuild step. You note that you are doing the actual build elsewhere, so you skipped the build phase in your CodePipeline"

Yes. I researched ways to find the best way to an update the ECS running tasks with the latest image in ECR, when a git push is carried out. If there is another way to do this that I have missed, please let me know.

I am looking into CodeBuild this morning.

Comment: You said you copied a script from the page you linked, but I don't see any scripts on that page, and I don't see them using AWS Lambda for anything on that page. So it's difficult to give you more concrete advice without being able to see exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: `def lambda_handler(event, context):
   task_definition_arn = ""
    container_name = "latest"
    image_uri = ""
    cluster_name = ""
    service_name = ""
   ecs = boto3.client('ecs')
    response = ecs.describe_task_definition(taskDefinition=task_definition_arn)
    task_definition = response['taskDefinition']
    for container_definition in task_definition['containerDefinitions']:
        if container_definition['name'] == container_name:
            container_definition['image'] = image_uri`

Comment: `response = ecs.register_task_definition(
        family=task_definition['family'],
        containerDefinitions=task_definition['containerDefinitions']
    )
    new_task_definition_arn = response['taskDefinition']['taskDefinitionArn']
    ecs.update_service(
        cluster=cluster_name,
        service=service_name,
        taskDefinition=new_task_definition_arn,
        forceNewDeployment=True  # Ensure a new deployment is triggered`

Comment: Sorry for the formatting issue. Also, because of character restrictions, I had to separate the code.

The above script should look at my image URI in ECR and update when a new image is uploaded. Also, in CodePipeline, I set GitLab to push in my branch.

What am I trying to achieve: I would like my running task in ECS to update whenever a push is initiated to GitLab on the branch that contains the dockerfile. 

I have a pipeline from GitLab to AWS ECR (which works fine), I just can't find a way to automatically update the task with the latest image

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. Click the edit button on your question to add additional details like that.

Comment: Also, your pipeline is going to run while GitLab is still building your docker image. You should probably have GitLab use the AWS CLI to trigger your pipeline once it has finished pushing the image to ECR.

Comment: I apologise. I'll put my code in the original question moving forward.

How would I set up GitLab to use AWS CLI to trigger my pipeline?